# server render status of 200 with empty object

Tags: express

please can someone help me to fix my server problem. So I want to make a post request that can add users to my database of a chat application, after I did the code in my router, it render me an empty object. this is my code on the user Router file:

```
userRouter.post("/", expressAsyncHandler(async(req, res)=> {
  const {name, fname, phone, email, password} = req.query;

  const newUser = {
    name: name, 
    fname: fname, 
    phone: phone, 
    email: email, 
    password: password};
allUsers.push(newUser);
res.status(200).send(newUser);

}));
```

Comment: Where is the database in your example code? There is no statement that _saves_ something to a database.

Comment: on mongo db my friend

Comment: like this: const data = {
    users: [{
        name:"Borhen",
        fname: "Bodré",
        phone: "0021625043843",
        email: "borem@gmail.com",
        image: "C:\Users\ADMIN\Pictures\Saved Pictures",
        password: bcrypt.hashSync("123456", 12),
        isAdmin: true
    },
 

    ]
};